# What are my chances of getting promotion?

Tags: promotion

So, I transferred to another unit because my SUP at the time was jealous of me and showed it. To make my story short, the new unit the Big Boss there was so nice to me. And  then my old supervisor friend  who is the  Big Boss Buddy started poisoning toward me. I felt the Big Boss acting strangely toward me. As I am a paranoid human being. I acted weird and started avoiding the Big Boss and even refused to cover a case for her.

I have recently gotten a lead position promotion at another unit with the same company. I know this sound like am mess but hear me. I then found out that the Big Boss cares about me and wanted me to be part of her unit. to make my story short , she even looked sad that I left. Anyhow, she now has a supervisor position open. I want it , because she fair and kind person. I want to work for someone like that. I think she is still pissed with me because I saw her talking to my current Big Boss who made the joke of stealing me from her. My previous Big Boss was not very happy about the joke and looked pissed. I need to make a damage control. I made a bad choice taking this lead position. I have applied for the supervisor position and not been in this lead position for even a month yet. I want that supervisor position. My old Big Boss is friends with the Company Director who makes decision over the hiring. I was at a Christmas part at my current unit and she joined us. She never even looked up to say hi but the other day at the party. She looked up and smiled to say hello.

Obviously, I self-sabotaged my career because of my paranoia about my previous supervisor who has good relationship with these people. However, everyone likes me and I want this opportunity. I feel like I ruined my career.  How do I do a damage control. As am overly stressed about this. They have not started the interviewing, this starts next week, part of me feel likes, I might get it and the other part says Nay .. you screwed up big time when you took the lead position but I was not aware the supervisor position was open.

Answer (score 3):

> So, I transeffered to another unit because my SUP at the time was
>   jealous of me and showed it.

That was good move. If you don't get along with boss and you have opportunity to transfer, it may be your best option

> To make my story short, the new unit the
>   Big Boss there was so nice to me. And then my old supvisor friend who
>   is the Big Boss Buddy started poisoning toward me.

That is pettiness and immaturity on that person's part. At the end of the day, it's God Almighty who knows your heart

> I felt the Big Boss
>   acting strangely toward me. As I am a paranoid human being. I acted
>   weird and started avoiding the Big Boss and even refused to cover a
>   case for her.

See, that's where you went wrong. You need to remain professional, doesn't matter what anyone thinks of you.

> Anyhow, I have recently gotten a lead position promotion
>   at another unit with the same company. I know this sound like am mess
>   but hear me.

How is this a mess? You got promoted to a lead position even though people don't like you. You must be doing something right

> I then found out that the Big Boss cares about me and
>   wanted me to be part of her unit. to make my story short , she even
>   looked sad that I left.

I don't think your Big Boss cares for you, she sees you are intelligent and competent (that's why you got promoted)

> Anyhow, she now has a supvisor position open.
>   I want it , becuase she fair and kind person. I want to work for
>   someone like that. I think she is still pissed with me because I saw
>   her talking to my current Big Boss who made the joke of stealing me
>   from her.

Do you want this position because it will help you? Then take it. Don't worry about if people are pissed at your jokes. Don't worry if your boss likes you are not. This is not some mother-in-law and daughter-in-law drama on TV

> My previous Big Boss was not very happy about the joke and
>   looked pissed. I need to make a damage control. I made a bad choice
>   taking this lead position.

No need for damage control. Just hold your head high, pull your shoulders back, and do an excellent job. More excellent job you do, more people will forget about your jokes. And if you really get super promotion, you can make worse jokes and everyone will laugh WITH YOU because you are smart BIG BIG BIG boss who controls their paycheck

> I have applied for the supervisor position
>   and not been in this lead position for even a month yet. I want that
>   supervisor position. My old Big Boss is friends with the Company
>   Director who makes decision over the hiring. I was at a christmas part
>   at my current unit and she joined us. She never even looked up to say
>   hi but the other day at the party. She looked up and smiled to say
>   hello.

Maybe she was being polite, but she sees you are useful to the company

> Obviously, I self-subatouged my career because of my paranoia
>   about my previous supervisor who has good relationship with these
>   people. However, everyone likes me and I want this opportunity. I feel
>   like I ruined my career. How do I do a damage control. As am overly
>   stressed about this. They have not started the enterviewing, this
>   starts next week, part of me feel likes, I might get it and the other
>   part says Nay .. you screwed up big time when you took the lead
>   position but I was not aware the Sup postion was open. Any advice will
>   help!

Ok stop beating yourself up over this. Do the best you can. You didn't sabotage your career. And even if you did, more accomplishments you make, less people will forget about any "sabotaging".

Happy Holidays!